# Process method does not receive full APDU command from host?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

The host sends the following command to applet to select EF file

```
00 A4 02 00 02 40 01
```

The purpose is to select EF file with ID `40 01` (which is specified in the data field of the command).

But when I debug the process(APDU apdu) method, the APDU buffer only contains the 5 first bytes `00 A4 02 00 02`. The data field is set to `00 00`. So my applet cannot select the EF using EF ID.

[image]

Could you tell me what is wrong with my APDU command above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the card (or emulator), the APDU buffer may only contain the APDU header fields (CLA, INS, P1, P2, Lc). Even if some cards automatically fill the data part of the command APDU into the APDU buffer, you can't rely on that behavior.

Instead, you have to explicitly instruct the card (or emulator) to retrieve the data part by calling the `setIncomingAndReceive()` method on the APDU object. But note that this method must only be called for case 3 and case 4 APDUs (i.e. APDU commands that contain a command data part). If there is no command data field, you should not call this method (case 1 and case 2 APDUs).

Comment: Thanks for your help! @Michael Roland
It solved my problem. My applet successful select EF.

Comment: But could you help me solve one more problem? 
After select EF, host send follow  command to read record "0x10" with "0x05" byte length of current EF. 
command: 00 B2 10 04 05 

Applet suppose to call readRecord() function when receive this command.
But in process() function, applet just run to setIncomingAndReceive() then don't run any more, don't return any SW bytes and also don't call readRecord() function. 
When I comment out setIncomingAndReceive() function, it work I execute the readRecord() function.

Comment: `setIncomingAndReceive()` must only be called for case 3 and case 4 APDUs (i.e. APDU commands that contain a command data part). You should not call this method for case 2 APDUs (i.e. an APDU that has an Le field but no Lc field).

Answer (score 0):

To get data in APDU buffer you need to call `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive()` and as in EMV specification AID for an applet is 5-16 bytes can't use less than 5 bytes.